# Recording user preferences and writing them to a database

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, sqlite

I need to record user preferences on a range of five projects by having them select from one of five radio buttons (5 for each project) which will be marked as 'first choice', 'second choice', etc... but I don't know how to go about recording this on the server (node.js express).

In case I'm not making myself clear, in an ideal world I'd have something like...

```js
//Student Project Preferences
app.get('/api/studentPrefs', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Route API/studentPrefs");
    console.log(req.query.name);
    var project_1 = req.query.project_1,
        project_2 = req.query.project_2,
        project_3 = req.query.project_3,
        project_4 = req.query.project_4,
        project_5 = req.query.project_5;
    
SUPER-pseudo-code...
----------
if(project_1 || project_2 || project_3 || project_4 || project_5 == 'choice_1') {
      INSERT INTO db (choice_1) VALUES (relevant topic)
    }
    else if(project_1 || project_2 || project_3 || project_4 || project_5 == 'choice_2') {
    ....etc
    }
});
```

```html
<fieldset>
<legend>&nbsp;Please choose your prefered project&nbsp;</legend>
<form id="studentPrefsForm" action="api/studentPrefs" method="get">
    <label for="projectChoice_1">Project Choice 1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="project_1" value="choice_1" />
    <input type="radio" name="project_1" value="choice_2" />
    <input type="radio" name="project_1" value="choice_3" />
    <input type="radio" name="project_1" value="choice_4" />
    <input type="radio" name="project_1" value="choice_5" />
    <br />
    <label for="projectChoice_2">Project Choice 2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="project_2" value="choice_1" />
    <input type="radio" name="project_2" value="choice_2" />
    <input type="radio" name="project_2" value="choice_3" />
    <input type="radio" name="project_2" value="choice_4" />
    <input type="radio" name="project_2" value="choice_5" />
    <br />
    <label for="projectChoice_3">Project Choice 3</label>
    <input type="radio" name="project_3" value="choice_1" />
    <input type="radio" name="project_3" value="choice_2" />
    <input type="radio" name="project_3" value="choice_3" />
    <input type="radio" name="project_3" value="choice_4" />
    <input type="radio" name="project_3" value="choice_5" />
    <br />
    <label for="projectChoice_4">Project Choice 4</label>
    <input type="radio" name="project_4" value="choice_1" />
    <input type="radio" name="project_4" value="choice_2" />
    <input type="radio" name="project_4" value="choice_3" />
    <input type="radio" name="project_4" value="choice_4" />
    <input type="radio" name="project_4" value="choice_5" />
    <br />
    <label for="projectChoice_5">Project Choice 5</label>
    <input type="radio" name="project_5" value="choice_1" />
    <input type="radio" name="project_5" value="choice_2" />
    <input type="radio" name="project_5" value="choice_3" />
    <input type="radio" name="project_5" value="choice_4" />
    <input type="radio" name="project_5" value="choice_5" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send my Choices">
</form>
</fieldset>
```

(*Sorry if the above JS explanation is a little too pseudo, I hope it's understandable*)

I know there are some issues with my 'ideal' solution, such as the IF statement not returning which project value is 'choice_1/2/3/4/5' so that I can write the project name into the relevant choice_x column in the db, but at this point I'll take anything.

As previously mentioned, I am a first year student so if you can see a better way of doing this, I am very much open to suggestions or critisism, and thanks again.

Comment: It's unclear to me what sorting has to do with this.

Comment: Ah, good point. I originally though that if i could get them in order of choice, I could write them to the db in order, but I don't know how returning the value would work. I'll amend the question, thanks.

Comment: What is the reason for having different choice columns in your database? They appear to be mutually exclusive, so  you could just store an integer in a single column, which is more scalable if you ever have more choices (6, 7, 8...)

Comment: @EricPhillips The user is to choose 1-5 (best to worst) for each project which will then be written to choice_1, choice_2 etc fields in the db so that the admin can decide which projects to allocate to which students.

Comment: Gotcha.  One thing to note is your condition won't work  (I know you said it's pseudo-code, but I still think you are making assumptions. 1 you can't chain conditions like that.  Each piece between your `|| operator` is treated like it's own condition, they don't all compare against the rightmost `=='choice_1`.  Your code will always return true, the leftmost check if simply asking `if project_1`, which javascript interprets as does `project_1` exist?  Yes, so always true.

Comment: Here is a more elegant way of getting your checked value.  Rather than doing a bunch of `if/else` just query the dom more directly. `document.querySelector("input[name='project_1']:checked").value`

Comment: @EricPhillips Pardon my ignorance, but isn't that client-side? How would i be able to match the choice number against the project name to be a able to write it to the db?

Answer (score -1):

Even though your JS code could be optimized it will do fine.
What you wrote is the client-side of the page. Depending on the platform/language you are using you need to pass these values to the server-side where the saving will happen.
Let us know what language you are using on the server side - php, .NET, etc.

Comment: Yes, the JS was meant as a very-pseudo pseudo-code to better explain, but  i have added what i have so far using node.js (express).